# Finding CRL distribution point URL from certificate using visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, wincrypt

I have to find CRL distribution point URL from a certificate. I managed to get obtain context (CERT_CONTEXT) of a certificate.

From this, how do I find CRL URL? To obtain publickeylength, there was a function CertGetPublicKeyLength. Similary is there anyway to find CRL Distribution point?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found the answer! You can use **CryptGetObjectUrl()** to obtain it.I would like to post the snippet of the code as it will be surely of some help to someone.

```
DWORD pcbUrlArray,pcbUrlInfo;
if(CryptGetObjectUrl(URL_OID_CERTIFICATE_CRL_DIST_POINT,pCert,CRYPT_GET_URL_FROM_PROPERTY | CRYPT_GET_URL_FROM_EXTENSION,NULL,&pcbUrlArray,NULL,&pcbUrlInfo,0))
{
    PCRYPT_URL_ARRAY urlArray = (PCRYPT_URL_ARRAY)malloc(pcbUrlArray * sizeof(CRYPT_URL_ARRAY));
    PCRYPT_URL_INFO  urlInfo = (PCRYPT_URL_INFO)malloc(pcbUrlInfo * sizeof(CRYPT_URL_INFO));

    if(CryptGetObjectUrl(URL_OID_CERTIFICATE_CRL_DIST_POINT,pCert,CRYPT_GET_URL_FROM_PROPERTY | CRYPT_GET_URL_FROM_EXTENSION,urlArray,&pcbUrlArray,urlInfo,&pcbUrlInfo,0))
    {
        for(int i=0;i<urlArray->cUrl;i++)
        wcout<<urlArray->rgwszUrl[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Basically you get the pCert (CERT_CONTEXT) through

```
WinHttpQueryOption( hRequest,WINHTTP_OPTION_SERVER_CERT_CONTEXT,&pCert,&dwLen);
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet but I think you have a bug there: CryptGetObjectUrl returns size in bytes, not in objects so malloc allocates way too much memory